# Animation remap driven by parameter

Tags: animation, drivers, timeline

I would like to remap a curve animation based on a parameter.
Say, a cube moves a complex animation on Z axis within 30 frames.
This animation needs to be syncronized with other objects with minimal adjustments, so I would like to have a controller to drive the frame of the cube animation to be displayed.

For example, if I animate the controller to go from value 0 to 15 within 10 frames, and later add a key with value 15, on frame 50, and a key of value 30 on frame 100, that would remap the cube animation.

In Maya, animation curves are driven by default by the "scene time" node. So it is easy to replace that node by a controller. But I am not sure how to accomplish that in Blender.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to convert the animation to a "clip" (Non-linear animation) - similar to Trax Editor in Maya. Converting an animation to a clip mixes all channels. But it is also possible to duplicate a clip and isolate specific channels to that clip for control.

The clip animation can be driven from another fcurve/driver by Enabling "Animated Strip Time". Animating this property will remap the animation on that selected "action".

Note that if the original Animation is 30 frames, and after editing the Strip Time curve the final animation extends this duration, it is necessary to adjust the clip "End" to be able to output the clip including this time remapping.